How do I make entities drop suspicious sand from specific structures using the set_loot_table function in Minecraft 1.21?
I am making a skyblock data pack and I want players to be able to get Sniffers, etc. from mob farms instead of from the Ocean Ruins structure. I can get a command block to successfully give me placeable suspicious sand that has the correct loot table, but when I try to make Husks drop that same block, the block they drop doesn't give anything when brushed.
I'm using the following loot table for Husks:
{
    "type": "minecraft:entity",
    "pools": [{
        "rolls": 1,
        "entries": [{
            "type": "minecraft:item",
            "name": "minecraft:suspicious_sand",
            "functions": [{
                "function": "minecraft:set_loot_table",
                "type": "minecraft:brushable_block",
                "name": "minecraft:archaeology/ocean_ruin_warm"
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "random_sequence": "minecraft:entities/husk"
}

The block I am getting from Husks returns the following data when I place it and run the /data get block command:
{
    components: {
        "minecraft:container_loot": {
            loot_table: "minecraft:archaeology/ocean_ruin_warm"
        }
    },
    x: 24,
    y: -23,
    z: 88,
    id: "minecraft:brushable_block"
}

The /give command I'm using is:
/give @p minecraft:suspicious_sand[
    minecraft:block_entity_data={
        id: "minecraft:brushable_block",
        LootTable: "minecraft:archaeology/ocean_ruin_warm"
    }
]

The correct data, which you get after placing the block the command generates, looks like this:
{
    LootTable: "minecraft:archaeology/ocean_ruin_warm",
    x: 24,
    y: -23,
    z: 89,
    id: "minecraft:brushable_block"
}

Is the set_loot_table function not what I'm looking for? Or how do I get the block that Husks drop to just have a LootTable tag instead of "components"? I also tried the set_custom_data function with similar results. The generated block has a "components" NBT tag instead of just a LootTable tag.
